# how do I change a color cell of the table on Typescript when using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this image:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, the cells have different colors. main action=1 green and action=0 red color.

I have this html code:

```
  <div class="row" colum>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <table *ngFor="let item of notification">
        <tr style="text-align:center">
          <ul> {{item.alarmdesc}}</ul>
          <ul> {{getProductName(item.device_serial)}}</ul>
          <ul> {{item.datetime_device | date:'d/MM/yyyy'}}</ul>
          <ul>
            <button style="border-style: groove; 
          width:70%; 
          height:30%; 
          margin: 15%;
          border: 1px solid rgb(198, 199, 198);
          padding: 10px;cursor: pointer;" (click)="OnAced(item.id)">main action: {{item.acted}}
        </button> 
        </ul>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Even your html sematic is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the conditional operator like that if action is in your item

```
<div [style.border-color]="item.action == 1 ? 'green' : 'red' "></div>
```

Comment: This works for me, but only that changes the color of the text, not the border. How to Change color in border, like in image in my post. Thank You

Comment: sure, with `border-color` instead of `color` it will work

Comment: Thank you. Work perfect :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using inline styling is a bad practice, you should use the css file related to the component.

You could do something like this:

css file:

```
.cell {
   text-align: center;
}

.green {
   color: "green";
}
```

component file:

```
isGreen(main): boolean {
  return main === 1
}
```

Then you could attach the css class to the element like this:

`<tr class="cell" [class.green]="isGreen(main)"></tr>`

Comment: an alternative could be if you need multiple classes and somewhat less code: [ngClass]="'{'green':isGreen(main), 'red':... }"

Comment: I implemented all the changes, but nothing happened in the show